# Change date format from YYYY/mm/dd to dd/mm/YYYY

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just a beginner in PHP. Can anyone help me on how to change the date and time format? Recently, it will appear like this

date: YYYY/mm/dd
time: HH:ii:ss

but what I want is like this:

date: dd/mm/YY
time: g:i: A

below is my current code:

```
      $mail->Body    = '<h3>Dear staff, </h3>
                        <p>Your meeting room booking details are as follows:</p> 

                        <p>Date : <b>'.$date = $_POST['date'].'</b></p>
                        <p>Time : <b>'.$timeFrom = $_POST['timeFrom'].' to '.$timeTo = $_POST['timeTo'].'</b></p>';
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

```php
// Aujourd'hui, le 10 Mars 2001, 5:16:18 pm, Fuseau horaire 
// Mountain Standard Time (MST)

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                   // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                           // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                         // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                             // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');       // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');     // It is the 10th day (10ème jour du mois).
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");                 // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \e\s\t\ \l\e\ \m\o\i\s'); // 17:03:18 m est le mois
$today = date("H:i:s");                           // 17:16:18
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                     // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (le format DATETIME de MySQL)
```

source : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

Your code :

```php
$date = date('2019/11/02 22:32:22');
$today = date("d/m/Y time: g:i A", strtotime($date));

echo $today;
```

Output : 02/11/2019 303211UTC: 10:32 PM

Comment: this does not convert anything